# How to add a PPA on a server?

Tags: server, ppa

The server version of Ubuntu does not have the [`add-apt-repository`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/add-apt-repository.1.html) command. How can I add a [Personal Package Archive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_Package_Archive) (PPA) to the server without this command?

Comment: in the latest version of synaptic you can add ppa's directly in the software sources instead of a deb line

Comment: - @Doug's answer is correct for _Ubuntu_ **16.04**
- @fossfreedom's answer is correct for _Ubuntu_ **14.04** On _Ubuntu_ **16.04** the right package is indeed `software-properties-common`, as shown by: $ type add-apt-repository add-apt-repository is hashed (/usr/bin/add-apt-repository) $ apt-file search /usr/bin/add-apt-repository software-properties-common: /usr/bin/add-apt-repository on previous versions it can be found indeed on `python-software-properties` ---
UPDATE: I comment it here, because I couldn't add it as a comment!

Comment: apt-add-repository works right out of the box.

Answer (score 197, accepted):

You can simply add the `add-apt-repository` command.  In 13.10 and later, you also need to run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

Side note: in 11.04 they added a symlink to `add-apt-repository` so it can be run as `apt-add-repository` which totally makes more sense to me.  Everything else apt starts with "apt".

NOTE: It's part of the `python-software-properties` package (before 13.10):

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```

Comment: Seeing it's actually a function of apt it is actually logical to me. "add repository with apt" > "apt-add-repository"

Comment: what if "python-software-properties" is already installed, and you still get "command not found" when trying to use "apt-add-repository"?

Comment: Did you also try "add-apt-respository"?  On versions before 11.04 you must put the "add" before the "apt".

Comment: what are you supposed to do when 'apt-get install python-software-properties' fails because it depends on python-curl, which is 'not installable'? On my 12.04 system, it complains that it's "unable to correct problems - you have held broken packages"

Comment: Is `software-properties-common` a set of defined tools or collection of utils?

Comment: Asker's question was "How can I add a Personal Package Archive (PPA) to the server **without** this command?" I wonder why he selected this answer.

Answer (score 75):

Let me teach you how to fish. `apt-file` enables you to find out which package provides a given file. `dpkg -S` does the same thing, but only for installed packages. `apt-file` works whether or not the package has been installed.

So, first you install apt-file: `sudo apt-get install apt-file`. You then need to update its information, just as you have to with apt-get: `sudo apt-file update`. Now it's ready for use:

```
$ apt-file search add-apt-repository
python-software-properties: /usr/bin/add-apt-repository
python-software-properties: /usr/share/man/man1/add-apt-repository.1.gz
```

So, in this case the next thing to do would be to install python-software-properties.

Comment: excellent tip - it perhaps shouldnt be buried in this question - a separate question would be a good idea to highlight this.

Comment: @fossfreedom Is this what you're talking about? - http://askubuntu.com/questions/13792/finding-out-what-package-a-command-came-from

Comment: Due to this tip I discovered that in 12.10 server apt-add-repository is located in software-properties-common (no longer in python-software-properties)

Comment: Why do I keep forgetting that this incredibly useful command exists! Great answer.

Answer (score 56):

It is not necessarily the best answer, but this will function:

The old-fashioned way (pre Ubuntu 9.10, they call it) of editing `/etc/apt/sources.list` still works. You will also need to get the GPG key on the system manually.

On older (pre 9.10) Ubuntu systems:

Step 1: Visit the PPA's overview page in Launchpad. Look for the heading that reads Adding this PPA to your system and click the Technical details about this PPA link.

Step 2: Use the Display sources.list entries drop-down box to select the version of Ubuntu you're using.

Step 3: You'll see that the text-box directly below reads something like this:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwibber-daily/ppa/ubuntu jaunty main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwibber-daily/ppa/ubuntu jaunty main
```

Copy those lines.

Step 4: Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

This will open a text editor containing the list of archives that your system is currently using. Scroll to the bottom of the file and paste the lines you copied in the step above.

Save the file and exit the text editor.

Step 5: Back on the PPA's overview page, look for the Signing key heading. You'll see something like:

1024R/72D340A3 (What is this?)

Copy the portion after the slash but not including the help link; e.g. just 72D340A3.

Step 6: Now you need to add that key to your system so Ubuntu can verify the packages from the PPA. In your terminal, enter:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 72D340A3
```

(Replace 72D340A3 with whatever you copied in the step 5.)

This will now pull down the PPA's key and add it to your system.

Step 7: Now, as a one-off, you should tell your system to pull down the latest list of software from each archive it knows about, including the PPA you just added:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now you're ready to start installing software from the PPA!

Comment: If no other quicker and more user friendly answer is given then i will put this one as the correct. It solves the problem in a "special" way ;)

Comment: While add-apt-repository is easier, in a server install I like to keep things lean, so I don't mind doing it manually. This was the answer I was looking for.

Comment: This method is way better than installing `apt-add-repository` and all the crap that comes with the requisite package.

Comment: This has proved to be very useful to me for a Vagrant setup using the shell provisioner. Thanks Broam!

Comment: software-properties-common package is HUGE, seems too much for just appending some text to a file and running a couple of commands. Such a waste of space while using in Docker. This answer is so very helpful!

Comment: This was really useful when I was having proxy issues

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since the OP asked how to get around *not* using add-apt-repository... Thanks a bunch for this one!

Answer (score 15):

`add-apt-repository` is provided by the package `python-software-properties`.

Thus if you should install via

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```

Comment: Thanks! I must say that I find a quite illogical name. Also, do you have any idea why I it is not standard installed?

Comment: agreed illogical - as to why, you could speculate that servers are usually 'fixed' in terms of running software.  Thus you dont need the 'luxury' of adding and removing repositories frequently ... end-of-speculation!

Comment: Why is it illogical? It's a set of python tools to deal with software properties. add-apt-repository is one of those tools.

Comment: I already have `python-software-properties` installed but I keep getting this error. I tried `apt-add` and `add-apt` notations, and none work... what to do?

Comment: @Mohamad - I would suggest you ask another question - link back to this Q and give as much details about the error that you see.

Comment: @Mohamad, because it's wrong, at least for Ubuntu 14.04. All you need to install is `software-properties-common`.

Answer (score 15):

Run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

And then you can add your repository running:

```
sudo add-apt-repository [REPOSITORY]
```

Renember to replace `[REPOSITORY]` with the repository name you want to add.

Comment: This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a debate with a colleague about this a few weeks ago.  Give

```
apt-add-repository
```

a try.  Doesn't need any other packages. Note that apt appears before add. Order does matter because add-apt-repository needs to be installed.

For those naysayers out there.  Give this Vagrant file a try.  Note, I'm starting from a fresh trusty image, and adding the ppa right out of the box.

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.ssh.username = "vagrant"

  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    sudo apt-add-repository ppa:george-edison55/cmake-3.x -y
    sudo apt update
    sudo apt upgrade
    sudo apt install -y virtualbox-guest-dkms
    sudo apt-get install -y curl g++ libpng12-dev  \
      libtiff5-dev libssl-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libpq-dev postgresql-client \
      postgresql pgadmin3 liblcms2-dev libcrypto++9 libcrypto++-dev \
      graphviz-dev libboost1.55-dev libboost-filesystem1.55-dev libboost-system1.55-dev \
      libexpat1-dev python-software-properties qtbase5-dev qttools5-dev  \
      libqt5svg5-dev qtscript5-dev qtdeclarative5-dev qtmultimedia5-dev \
      libsqlite3-dev qt5-default cmake

  SHELL
end
```

Update:  Just to clarify, it looks like the cloud images for ubuntu precise and up have the correct package already installed.  So whether we are talking cloud-init scripts or a vagrant file, apt-add-repository is present.  Since add-apt-repository is in the same package that should work as well.

Comment: Order doesn't matter. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/83489/what-is-the-difference-between-add-apt-repository-apt-add-repository.

Comment: Do explain why this vagrant file works then.  Note I'm not argueing that they do something different.  They do exactly the same thing.  You just need a package for the add-apt, where as the other works from scratch.

Comment: @atifm: See [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/55484/83700):
    $ apt-file search add-apt-repository
    software-properties-common: /usr/bin/add-apt-repository
    software-properties-common: /usr/share/man/man1/add-apt-repository.1.gz
    $ apt-file search apt-add-repository
    software-properties-common: /usr/bin/apt-add-repository
    software-properties-common: /usr/share/man/man1/apt-add-repository.1.gz

Comment: @tricasse: Thanks for the link to apt-file, that'll be useful elsewhere.  So your right, they are in the same package as verified by apt-file.  That said, it looks like the ubuntu cloud images (for vagrant) for precise and trusty has the package already installed.  Not sure if this was always the case, but it seems to be the case at the moment