# How can I install add-apt-repository

Tags: 11.04, add-apt-repository

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add a PPA on a server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38021/how-to-add-a-ppa-on-a-server)

When I want to use a package from Launchpad it tells me to execute the command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:user/ppa-name
```

However, on my freshly installed Natty server box, this command does not exist. (`sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found`)

How can I install `add-apt-repository`?