# What is the difference between add-apt-repository & apt-add-repository?

Tags: add-apt-repository

Difference between `add-apt-repository` & `apt-add-repository`  ?

Comment: first time to know that there is a `apt-add-repository` command i always see it `add-apt-repository`, it is good as i always use command in the form of `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` and `apt-add-repository` has the same form (Good)

Comment: Is there a corresponding command for the newer `apt` command? I know there is `apt edit-sources` which lets one edit the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file with a text editor. But is there a quick way to add/remove sources with just the `apt` command?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

They're the same command, someone just added the inverse because people kept mixing the command up and typing it wrong.

Answer (score 27):

An easy way to find this out would have been:

```
minibun:~> ls -l `which apt-add-repository`
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 2011-08-26 15:36 /usr/bin/apt-add-repository -> add-apt-repository
```

You can see that `apt-add-repository` is simply a symlink to `add-apt-repository` :)

Comment: This doesn't prove anything: e.g. `/usr/bin/xzcat` is a symlink to `xz`, but works quite differently.

Comment: @Ruslan `xzcat is equivalent to xz --decompress --stdout.`

Comment: @Shayan exactly, and my point was that the mere fact that a name is a symlink to something doesn't prove that the functionality between two names is identical.

Comment: @Ruslan Yep, I added it for reference so others can see why it's different :)