# "Packages have unmet dependencies" while installing Gimp 2.7.5 on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dependencies, deb, gimp

I have been trying to install Gimp 2.7.5 for a few days now, but keep getting this message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

gimp: Depends: python-gtk2 (>= 2.8.0) but 2.24.0-2 is to be installed
      Depends: libc6 (>= 2.11) but 2.13-20ubuntu5.1 is to be installed
      Depends: libfontconfig1 (>= 2.8.0) but 2.8.0-3ubuntu2 is to be installed
      Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0) but 2.24.0-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
      Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.31.2) but 2.30.0-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
      Depends: libgs9 (>= 8.61.dfsg.1) but 9.04~dfsg-0ubuntu11.5 is to be installed
      Depends: libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.24.0) but 2.24.6-0ubuntu5 is to be installed
      Depends: libgudev-1.0-0 (>= 147) but 1:173-0ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
      Depends: libjpeg62 (>= 6b1) but 6b1-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
      Depends: librsvg2-2 (>= 2.14.4) but 2.34.1-2 is to be installed
      Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4) but 1:1.2.3.4.dfsg-3ubuntu3 is to be installed
```

Where would I get the things the program wants, and how?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Are you trying to install this package via the Ubuntu Software Center, or the commandline?

Comment: Ubuntu Software Center or through Terminal?

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime(I assume Gimp 2.6 is now uninstallable, I've also had this problem), you can try and use [GIMP 2.74](http://alcides-mp.com/software/gimp-2-7-4-binaries-for-ubuntu/). There's not much difference from 2.75. It still has the Single-window mode and Text input improvements.

Answer (score 1):

You have 4 options:

Install from [this](https://launchpad.net/~matthaeus123/+archive/mrw-gimp-svn) ppa. <--What I think you should do
For directions on how to do that check [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38021/how-to-add-a-ppa-on-a-server).
The landing page for that PPA tells you what other PPAs you have to add to get the 2.7.5 install working.

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu oneiric main

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ricotz/testing/ubuntu oneiric main
```

Installing a bunch of ppas may or may not completely fix it with dependency issues though.

Dynamically compile all the dependencies and have what looks like a normal gimp install, but could break other software. - don't even think about it

Statically compile all the dependencies and link it all in to one huge gimp executable. - possible, but not likely

Wait until the main-line dependency system converges at the package level you want.