# add-apt-repository missing from mini.iso

Tags: add-apt-repository

I downloaded the Ubuntu 12.10 mini.iso today.
My intentions were to install the Razor-QT ppa.

I found [this here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38021/how-to-add-a-ppa-on-a-server)

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```

Did not work. I can't locate the package.

Comment: Try apt-add-repository. Doesn't need the python-software-properties package and does exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The package was moved. I found it: [Replace python-software-properties Depends with 'software-properties-common'](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cloud-init/+bug/1021418)

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

Comment: If you found it , mark your answer as the best answer.

Comment: lol, I tried but it said I can't accept it for two more days.