# Upgrading MAAS from 1.5.4 to 1.7.0 or latest on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, maas

I am trying to upgrade MAAS from 1.5.4 to maas 1.7.0.
Not sure about the steps to follow.
And which versions of maas are supported by ubuntu 14.04

currently runnuing

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty

Linux ubuntu 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu
```

*How should I proceed?*

Answer (score 1):

I had this question myself and newell from the IRC channel helped me out in realising that the PPA was missing, but this might not be your case. These steps will help you get the update without compromising your other packages (please read the answers to the linked questions, they might be useful to your case and needs).

1. You should check if there are any held back packages, and if maas is
   one of them, when you do:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```

   If there are, and they are maas related, you can skip the following step, to add the Maas PPA.
2. To add the Personal Package Archive (PPA) for Maas's stable version
   (`ppa:maas-maintainers/stable`) you can do

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository ppa:maas-maintainers/stable
   ```

   One normally installs Maas on a server so apt-add-repository or
   add-apt-repository, are not available. To install `apt-add-repository/add-apt-repository`, in order to add the ppa, use the following [How to add a PPA on a Server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38021/how-to-add-a-ppa-on-a-server#38035). After adding the ppa use   the command from step 1.
3. Assuming you see held back packages, this means that the software
   you are to upgrade has new dependencies that it did not have on the
   version you currently have installed. You can have maas (or any
   package in this situation) installed by doing:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install <list of held back packages>
   ```

   You could do a `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, but it would mean
   getting more than just the held back software listed on `apt-get
   upgrade`. The latest version of ubuntu would also be installed. I
   took this information from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/185402) (the link points to the answer
   I used, the others hint at the fact that `dist-upgrade` and other
   commands, such as aptitude, might do more than what you want).