# MAAS: 1.5.4 to 1.8.0 migrations issue

Tags: server, upgrade, juju, maas

I have attempted an upgrade from 1.5.4 to 1.8.0 (from the "stable" line of the PPA) on ULTS14 to go with an upgrade of Juju to 1.24.5 and I get the appended migration error.

Is there a away to get it to progress beyond that point
Is it possible to revert to 1.5.4 (or to 1.7.6 for example)?
What can I do at this point?

The MAAS instance manages 12 physical servers which are used by a Juju instance.

There is some previous material suggesting a reinstall of the packages, and I tried that, but that did not change the outcome, which I think depends on a data migration issue.
[Upgrading MAAS from 1.5.4 to 1.7.0 or latest on ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/581987/upgrading-maas-from-1-5-4-to-1-7-0-or-latest-on-ubuntu-14-04)

[Python error during MAAS upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/665170/python-error-during-maas-upgrade)

```
 * Restarting PostgreSQL 9.3 database server
   ...done.
Syncing...
Creating tables ...
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)

Synced:
 > django.contrib.auth
 > django.contrib.contenttypes
 > django.contrib.sessions
 > django.contrib.sites
 > django.contrib.messages
 > django.contrib.staticfiles
 > piston
 > south

Not synced (use migrations):
 - maasserver
 - metadataserver
(use ./manage.py migrate to migrate these)
Running migrations for maasserver:
 - Migrating forwards to 0138_perf_index_on_node_events.
 > maasserver:0121_recompute_storage_size
Error in migration: maasserver:0121_recompute_storage_size
Traceback (most recent call last):
......
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "metadataserver_noderesult" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."."name", "metadataserver_noderesult"."data" FROM "metadatas...
```

To study the state of the MAAS database I have used this SQL query and the results look plausible and consistent, so I guess that the upgrade did not damaged it:

```
select
  m.mac_address                         as "Ethernet",
  w.name                                as "network",
  w.id                                  as "netid",
  w.ip                                  as "subnet",
  l.ip                                  as "lease",
  w.default_gateway                     as "gw",
  n.hostname                            as "node",
  n.storage                             as "storage",
  n.power_parameters                    as "WoL"
from
  maasserver_macaddress                 as m
    left join maasserver_macaddress_networks as m2n
    on m.id = m2n.macaddress_id
      left join maasserver_network      as w
      on m2n.network_id = w.id
  left join maasserver_dhcplease        as l
    on l.mac = m.mac_address
      inner join maasserver_node        as n
      on m.node_id = n.id
order by
  n.hostname,
  w.ip,
  m.mac_address
```

Comment: BTW I looked at the existing MAAS DB and it looks complete and consistent. There is a relation 'metadataserver_nodecommissionresult' rather than 'metadataserver_noderesult' so I guess that in some release between 1.5.4 and 1.8.0 it might have been renamed and this was not captured by one of the 'migrations' script.

Comment: I have installed on a test system from scratch 1.5.4, 1.7.6 and 1.8.0 and the current database schema seems to match pretty closely 1.7.6 with the exception of 'metadataserver_noderesult' that has a fairly close equivalent.

Comment: There is now a related issue entry about preventing this from happening [1495064](https://bugs.launchpad.net/maas/+bug/1495064) and the best guess is that this happened because of an ordering issue among the migration patches.

Comment: It turns out that MAAS being a Django 1.6 application uses [Django South](http://south.aeracode.org/) to handle updates to the database schema, and that the default MAAS upgrade applies them potentially in the wrong order (first all those for the `maasserver` and then all those for the `metadataserver`). Since the updates applied are recorded recovery could be very simple. Testing it.

Comment: The  test where I install 1.5.4, load the quasi-1.7.6 database, and then upgrade to 1.7.6 succeeded, and only the missing 0015 migration was applied. The test where I installed 1.5.4, loaded the quasi-1.7.6 database, upgraded to 1.8.x (presently 1.8.2) failed as expected on migration 0121, and then downgrading to 1.7.6 succeeded with only migration 0015 installed. But this requires hand-editing some state in the DPKG database. And it left configurations in a state "to be reviewed".

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that removing *carefully* the not-quite-installed 1.8.0 packages and installing 1.7.6 work as expected as per the tests already done. The `metadataserver` app 0015 "migration" gets applied and that leaves the migrations at 0120 for the `maassserver` app and 0015 for `metadataserver` which happen to be the right migration level for 1.7.6.

**Important note**: to remove the not-quite-installed 1.8.0 packages takes some hand-editing of `/var/lib/dpkg/info/status` and sometimes a related file to fake them being installed when they aren't.

Answer (score 0):

This is being tracked under [bug 1495064](https://bugs.launchpad.net/maas/+bug/1495064).

It will be fixed in MAAS 1.9.0 and MAAS 1.8.3.