# sudo: unable to execute /usr/bin/add-apt-repository: No such file or directory

Tags: apt, package-management, permissions, ppa, repository

Getting `sudo: unable to execute /usr/bin/add-apt-repository: No such file or directory` error while adding repository:-

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:neovim-ppa/unstable
```

`/usr/bin/add-apt-repository` file permissions:-

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6123 Oct 25 14:16 /usr/bin/add-apt-repository*
```

Let me know if more details needed. Thanks!!
[I checked all related questions but didn't find any Let me know if I'm making duplicate]

Output of `ldd /usr/bin/python3`

```
ldd: /usr/bin/python3: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/38021/504066

Comment: After adding `python3`. It's working fine. Thanks @muru

Comment: @Anonymous that's great! Maybe you could post an answer showing how you did that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into the same issue. Turned out the cause was that /usr/bin/python3 was not linked to an executable.

Here's how to solve it:

- Install Python if you have not done so.
- Pick the Python executable you want to use, say python3.5. Go to /usr/bin and you'll see installed executable like python2.7, python3.5, python3.6.
- Run the following command, assuming you want to python3.5

```
ln -s /usr/bin/python3.5 /usr/bin/python3
```