# How do I fix add-apt-repository command "isn't supported" error in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

I am trying to install Wine however when I run:

```
~$ sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ cosmic main'
```

I get:

```
LSB codename: 'bionic'.
This codename isn't currently supported.
Please check your LSB information with "lsb_release -a".
```

I've already tried (in order):

```
sudo apt-get install python3-software-properties
sudo apt-get install apt-file
sudo apt install python-software-properties
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-software-properties
sudo apt install --reinstall software-properties-common
```

(I followed the first two answers from [How to add a PPA on a server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38021/how-to-add-a-ppa-on-a-server)).  When I search for add-apt-repository, I get:

```
~$  apt-file search add-apt-repository

software-properties-common: /usr/bin/add-apt-repository
software-properties-common: /usr/share/man/man1/add-apt-repository.1.gz
```

How do I get add-apt-repository to work?

Comment: If it's 18.04, why are you trying to add repository for cosmic. Try replacing cosmic with bionic, Moreover, wine is in official Ubuntu repository. Therefore, you can drop the idea of adding a repository.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: This may be a dumb question but how do you tell if you should run Bionic or Cosmic?  I thought 18.04 corresponded to bionic.  Should I use packages for newer versions of Ubuntu from now on?

Comment: Look at the command you used to add repository. It clearly has cosmic in its name which corresponds to 18.10 while bionic is 18.04. ***Should I use packages for newer versions of Ubuntu from now on?:*** No. They might create dependency issues. Try K7AAY's answer once.

Answer (score 0):

For Wine to work, you need 32-bit capability, and since you are using 18.04, you need to use *bionic*, not *cosmic*, so these commands are more appropriate:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
wget -qO - https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key | sudo apt-key add - 
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```