# Source code for 'df' command

Tags: 11.10, disk, source

Can someone tell me how to locate the source code for the 'df' command. My operating system is Ocelot.

Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

First, [find out what package the `df` command comes from](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13792/finding-out-what-package-a-command-came-from). This will turn out to be `coreutils`.

Then run the command

```
apt-get source coreutils
```

to get the source code for the package containing the `df` command.

Comment: Props for teaching a man to fish.

Comment: If you give a man a fish, that man now knows where to find fish. 0If you teach a man to fish, you just destroyed your market base.

Answer (score 1):

`df` is a part of coreutils package. You can get source either from [GNU website](http://www.gnu.org/s/coreutils/) or you can get the source package from [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/+source/coreutils)